# Разрешить клик только по двум элементам в блоке

Tags: javascript

Есть такой блок:

```
<div id="main">
<div class="photo">Photo</div>
<a href="">Link</a>
</div>
```

Очень давно задавал вопрос похожий, не могу его найти. Смысл в том, чтобы если пользователь кликает по блоку **#main**, то срабатывает redirect. Но если пользователь в блоке по элементам **.photo** и **a**, то переход не срабатывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрим на `event.target` - если это `#main`, то redirect. Иначе - нет redirect-а. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/z5t4r666/)

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая штука, как `event.stopPropagation();`.

Более подробно, например, тут можно посмотреть [bubbling and capturing](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing).

Пример на jquery:

```
$("#main").on("click", function(e) {
    alert("main");
})

$(".photo").on("click", function(e) {
    alert("photo");
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```